# Web scraping from strong tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

How do i pull the data from the strong tag?

```html
HTML code:
<div class="store-views"><span class="caption">VISIT COUNT</span><br><strong>336</strong></div>
```

I have tried soup.find("strong") and soup.find("div", class_="store-views") but it either comes up with the wrong data or "None"

Comment: `soup.select_one(".store-views strong").text` should work. Bud does `print(soup.prettify())` show that the tag is there?

Comment: Still have it showing up with 'NoneTpe' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Do `print(soup.prettify())` and check if the `<strong>` tag is there. It might be injected via Javascript and beautifulsoup doesn't see it.

Comment: Yes, when i do print(soup.prettify())  it doesn't show up

Comment: Is there an url to share?

Comment: https://store.bricklink.com/legoseller9997&utm_content=globalnav#/shop

Answer (score 0):

That value is dynamically added, possibly from google analytics. You can use selenium to automate browser so you can capture this value when added:

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://store.bricklink.com/legoseller9997&utm_content=globalnav#/shop')
print(d.find_element_by_css_selector('.store-views strong').text)
d.quit()
```

The other data comes from an ajax request:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://store.bricklink.com/ajax/clone/store/searchitems.ajax?showHomeItems=1&sid=1663355', headers= {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}).json()
print(r)
```