# Transfer HTML content to Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, css-selectors

How do I transfer **all the innertext between the top and bottom TR-tag** including the HREF-link in this snippet to **ONE** excel cell using vba? TR-tag is the outermost tag under the main TABLE-tag. With this code I just can transfer the innertext of each TR or TD in multiple Cells. Once the content is transfered to one Excel-cell, I will try to seperate&transfer the text-parts to different cells with string-operations.

```
Set element = html.querySelectorAll("tr")   'or td
For L = 0 To element.Length - 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 2, 2) = element.Item(x).innerText
Next x
```

Even much better would be to get each text row into an Excel cell, but **arranged horizontally!** (cell a,b,c...) as a row till the next "TR to TR section" which must beginn in the next line/row (1,2,3...) in Excel. (I'm trying to build a proper table here since each record in HTML consists of multiple contents as below.)  A problem is also that each text is inside another tag: "nobr", "b", "p" and some just in "td".

Here ist he snippet.

```html
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left">
        <nobr>TEXT&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr>
    </td>
    <td valign="center" align="left">
        <b>
            <a target="_blank" href="idx.php?button=showZvg&ndd_id=2444&land_nve=lv">
                <nobr>TEXT8&nbsp;(Detailansicht)</nobr>
            </a>
        </b>
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="right">
        <nobr>TEXT</nobr>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left">TEXT</td>
    <td colspan="2" valign="center" align="left">
        <b>TEXT</b>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left">TEXT</td>
    <td colspan="2" valign="center" align="left">
        <b>
            TEXT
        </b>
        TEXT
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left">
        <nobr>TEXT</nobr>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" valign="center" align="left">
        <b>
            <p>TEXT</p>
        </b>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left">Termin</td>
    <td valign="center" align="left">TEXT</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: copy paste table outerHTML via clipboard to Excel. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51938256/6241235

Comment: Thanks to @QHARR are you a secret computer scientist at "google x"?  ;-) copy&paste the outerhtml with MSXML2.XMLHTTP works well, but now I have the whole sourcecode-content of the TABLE-tag in one cell....

Comment: If you copy the outerHTML of the table tag the table should be replicated in excel not just in one cell. Side note: there is a company x: https://x.company/projects/ . Google x cannot deny or confirm. You copy paste with the code in the link i.e. by creating a clipboard object.

Comment: You are right, it was a code error: I had `ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = objCBData.GetText` but it had to be `ActiveSheet.Paste`. But I am still facing the same problem: the table is arranged vertically! With queryselectorall "td" I would have achieved the same result. I need the results in rows, not in columns!

Comment: I know google x for a long time, reminds me of the series EUREKA: genius scientists who discover crazy things :-) by the way, i accidentally clicked the wrong flag button at your first answer, very sorry (>beginner!<)

Comment: is there an url?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_(American_TV_series)

Comment: You use selenium to open browser with python. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67044654/6241235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to transpose the table but the table is irregular. I make an assumption that when there are more than 2 child nodes you want to combine that text and place into a single cell:

```
Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable, row As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow, column As MSHTML.HTMLTableCell
Dim r As Long, c As Long

Set table = html.querySelector("table")

With ActiveSheet
    r = 1
    For Each row In table.Rows
         c = 1
         Dim combined As String: combined = vbNullString
         For Each column In row.Children
             If row.Children.Length > 2 And c > 1 Then
               combined = combined & Chr$(32) & Trim$(column.innerText)
             Else
                 .Cells(IIf(c = 1, 1, c), r) = Trim$(column.innerText)
             End If
             If row.Children.Length > 2 And c = row.Children.Length Then
                 .Cells(row.Children.Length - 1, r) = Trim$(combined)
             End If
             c = c + 1
        Next
        r = r + 1
    Next
End With
```

---

**Based on actual scenario:**

1. Due to flat sibling structure of table (i.e. can't easily divide into result blocks (except perhaps by the blank rows) I process all rows, and each time see
   "Aktenzeichen" increment the output row counter by 1.
2. All rows between increments will supply the data for the current row column.
3. Have a dictionary which has all the possible headers as keys and `vbNullString` as value; as loop rows, set current header to first column value and add the adjacent `td` value to the dictionary; against that header. If the header is blank, and not a blank row, seek the `a` tag link (`Pdf-Link`).
4. A new blank dictionary is grabbed (has the keys but nullString values) each time row increment.
5. Before incrementing row again, empty current row into an oversized array. This array is sized once headers are known and estimates for more the expected number of results. The `results` array is passed `ByRef`, along with the current row number, so that it can be updated by a separate sub.
6. At the end, after all rows are processed, the `results` array is written to the sheet in the desired tabular format. Headers are added to the row above where the results are written.

**Note:** I think selenium basic is still needed for downloading the pdfs.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetDataZvgPort()
    Const URL = "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen"
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object

    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

    With xhr
        .Open "POST", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send "land_abk=ni&ger_name=Peine&order_by=2&ger_id=P2411"
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable, r As Long, c As Long, headers(), row As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow
    Dim results() As Variant, html2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    headers = Array("Aktenzeichen", "Amtsgericht", "Objekt/Lage", "Verkehrswert in €", "Termin", "Pdf-Link")

    ReDim results(1 To 100, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

    Set table = html.querySelector("table")
    Set html2 = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Dim lastRow As Boolean

    For Each row In table.Rows
        lastRow = False
        Dim header As String

        html2.body.innerHTML = row.innerHTML
        header = Trim$(row.Children(0).innerText)

        If header = "Aktenzeichen" Then          'start of new block. Assumes all blocks have this
            r = r + 1
            Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set dict = GetBlankDictionary(headers)
        End If

        If dict.Exists(header) Then dict(header) = Trim$(row.Children(1).innerText)

        If (header = vbNullString And html2.querySelectorAll("a").Length > 0) Then
            dict("Pdf-Link") = Replace$(html2.querySelector("a").href, "about:blank", "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php")
            lastRow = True
        ElseIf header = "Termin" Then
            If row.NextSibling.NodeType = 1 Then lastRow = True
        End If

        If lastRow Then
            populateArrayFromDict dict, results, r
        End If
    Next

    results = Application.Transpose(results)
    ReDim Preserve results(1 To UBound(headers) + 1, 1 To r)
    results = Application.Transpose(results)

    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub populateArrayFromDict(ByVal dict As Scripting.Dictionary, ByRef results() As Variant, ByVal r As Long)
    Dim key As Variant, c As Long

    For Each key In dict.Keys
        c = c + 1
        results(r, c) = Replace$(dict(key), " (Detailansicht)", vbNullString)
    Next

End Sub

Public Function GetBlankDictionary(ByRef headers() As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary, i As Long

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        dict(headers(i)) = vbNullString
    Next

    Set GetBlankDictionary = dict
End Function
```

Comment: No, it's the page I sent the code above. the damn site i've been wrestling with for a week now. How do I explain this? So: now it looks like this in Excel: (H:header, c:content). ROW 1: H1,H2,H3....again H1,H2,H3...and so on. And: ROW 2: c1,c2,c3....(from house1) again c1,c2,c3...(from house2) and so on. but my intention: row1: H1,H2,H3 as Headers, row2: c1,c2,c3(from block1 as content(properties of Hous1), row3: c1,c2,c3(from block2 as content(properties of Hous2).

Comment: I think you probably mean you want to split some of the text within the tds into separate rows. However, I will need an image of what the output should look like to work from. Please use the edit button below your question to add a picture of what output should look like.

Comment: Automate a browser with vba

Comment: @Jasco Sorry for the short interjection. I would just like to point out that Selenium is also available as Selenumbasic for VBA. You have to make sure that the Seleniumbasic version matches the version of the browser you are using and the version of the corresponding WebDriver: https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/

Comment: @Jasco You must paste the pic to your posting. Edit it. It's not possible in comments.

Comment: You've missed the rest of the html e.g. the next rows and the column containing the href. I need that html. You can paste the entire table html into pastebin.com or better yet, please update question with instructions on how to generate the table within a webpage I can access.

Comment: @Jasco My tip: leave it for today. It's Friday, it's 9:10pm in Germany. I know this because I also live in Germany. My second tip is: don't delete this question again either. There are definitely people who want to help you. But give them time to do so. They do it completely for free in their free time. I know this so well because I had programmed something to one of your questions, but I couldn't answer anymore. Very frustrating. I know that you want to find a solution for your parents and that's honourable. But please don't get carried away (for yourself). Sorry, but that's my impression.

Comment: @Zwenn thanks brother, I really appreciate your advice. It's just that my parents are running out of time and they're really struggling nervously. I have to help them. Anyway, have a restful weekend and thanks again for the sympathy.

Comment: ^^ that is some very good advice. I think there are solutions but I, for example, need to fit this in around exam revision. I will look again tomorrow.

Comment: @QHARR...without your constant support, I would have given up long ago. I am in your debt, thank you very much and also to you a nice weekend.

Comment: Erm.... referrer has been in my code all along hasn't it? In the answer I gave to your last question it is in the commented out bit where I said you definitely need a referer header but possibly something else. Btw I updated answer above to give you your table.

Comment: @QHARR I'm sorry if I missed your referer hint, it was probably due to sleepless nights. Fantastic work with the new code, thanks very much. But I get an error message from excel here `Public Function populateArrayFromDict(ByVal dict As Scripting.Dictionary, ByRef results() As Variant, ByVal r As Long) As Variant`. (translates from geman:) **user defined type not defined**

Comment: you need to go vbe :> tools > references > and scroll down until you find MIcrosoft Scripting Runtime library and make sure it is ticked. I should have made that clear. Apologies.

Comment: I have added more detail regarding the approach.

Comment: @QHARR: Elegant and perfectly working code. Ingenious. I wish I had anywhere near that level of competence. Many thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231271/discussion-between-qharr-and-jasco).

Comment: @Jasco see chat invite